# Create custom tableView cell textField or textView tag

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tags, textfield

I have multiple tableView, each tableView I have txtName and txtNote. txtName is textField, txtNote is textView. I try to send textField tag and textView tag, but custom (not indexPath.row only). because tag is Int, so I custom it like this:

```
let tagString = String(row) + String(703)
        print("tagString:\(tagString)")
        let intTagString = Int(tagString)
        cell.txtNote.tag = intTagString!
```

when print I got custom tagString example like 0703, 1703, 2703 and etc.

But when I try to get txtNote tag with this :

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    print("textview text:\(textView.text!) and text tag:\(textView.tag)")
}
```

text tag: only print last intTagString as 703 only.

How to correct this so I can get whole custom tag?

Comment: Where did you set tag for textView? & Your mean is tableView with multiple cell, each cell have txtName and txtNote?

Comment: I set tag from storyboard. yes, each tableView has txtName and txtNote. not multiple cell, but multiple tableView.

Answer (score 3):

When you cast a literal integer string to integer, first zeros (0000...) will be omitted. That's why `"00703"` becomes `703`

You can correct this by adding a 'one' at the first place: `"100703"` --> `100703`

---

Edit. The whole solution using custom delegate:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView!
    let ReusedID = "**MyCell**"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView = UITableView.init(frame: view.bounds, style: .grouped)
        tableView.register(MyCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: ReusedID)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 8 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ReusedID, for: indexPath)
        if let cell = cell as? MyCell {
            cell.configCell(somethingHere: nil, parent: tableView, with: indexPath)
        }
        return cell
    }
}

/// Create a custom delegate for tableview
protocol MyTableViewDalegate: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, didChange textView: UITextView, at indexPath: IndexPath)
}

/// [***] Implement the custom delegate
extension ViewController: MyTableViewDalegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, didChange textView: UITextView, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("table view cell did change with indexpath: ", indexPath)
    }
}

/// Custom Cell Class which implement text view delegate
class MyCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    var textView: UITextView!
    var cellIndexPath: IndexPath!
    var parent: UITableView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        textView = UITextView.init()
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.text = "Lorem ipsum sit dolor"
        addSubview(textView)
        textView.sizeToFit()
    } // End of UI preparation

    func configCell(somethingHere: Any?, parent: UITableView?, with indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.parent = parent
        self.cellIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    // TextView Delegate
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let delegate = parent?.delegate as? MyTableViewDalegate
        delegate?.tableView(parent, didChange: textView, at: cellIndexPath) // <== HERE
        // The delegate will be called in [***] section above
    }
}
```

Comment: or switch it become String(703) + String(row)?

Comment: yes, every rule you prefer. but if you want to take those tag values to do something later you need apply your rule to filter back the number you want.

Comment: later, I create string from that Int and seperate last character, because last character I set never above 9. So it is only one character never double like 10 and etc. So I got which tableView and I got which row that being editing.

Comment: why didn't you apple a `delegate` for this? It's more clear and safer to handle your case.

Comment: so, I try from cell for row at

Comment: Go to the next comment I'll show you the whole solution. :))